# Deleting entity with foreign key lazy-loaded property which is not loaded yet in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this example entity:

```
public class A{

[Key]
public int ID {get; set;} 

public virtual List<B> BsCollection {get; set;}

public A(){

   BsCollection = new List<B>();
}

}
```

In my code I load object `A` with ID 1, but do not lazy load the `B` collection. 
Then I want to delete the `A` object from the database and delete all the `B` objects in the database which relate to the `A` object I'm deleting at that point.

But how can I delete them if I haven't lazy loaded them yet?

Is there a way I can make such a delete without a useless call from `B` collection to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either:

1. Use Cascade delete defintion.    [cascade delete info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)
   or
2. attach the objects to delete to the context 
   Then call **Remove**

Note: You can put the full object into the context by way of read.
It is however possible to delete and entry by attaching a shell object with only the key set.
ie new Poco(){id= x};   the rest of the poco need not be set if you intend to delete it next.
If you dont know the Ids to be deleted, you will need to "load" them.

EDIT: If you have references. You will need to remove the dependent entries first.
Edit 2:add New Poco() comment

Comment: The Remove method does not work. It still throws error because of the foreign key :/

Comment: How can I attach the objects to the context, when none of the lazy loaded objects is not loaded yet? :) there must another way how to deal with these issues...

Comment: The note in the answer explains that you can attach a shell object.  Ill extend to make more obvious